# Probability Question (Equally likely sample points)

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

An airport bus deposits 25 passengers at 7 stops. Each passenger is as likely to get off at any stop as at any other, and the passengers act independently of one another. The bus makes a stop only if someone wants to get off. What is the probability that nobody gets off at the third stop?

I know the total possibilities are $7^{25}$, but I am not sure about the numerator.

Since no one is getting off at the third stop, that would assume they are getting off on the other 6 stops. So would the answer be $\frac{6^{25}}{7^{25}}$?

Comment: Yes you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

If you understand the reason of $7^{25}$, you should understand the value of $6^{25}$.